# Using if with or

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it possible to use IF with OR to check if one condition applies to 2 or more variables?

I need it like this, but when I put `or` between them, it doesn't work.
I've tried like this too:

```
elif x OR y >0: # (for Quadrant II)
```

My code:

```
x = int(input()
y = int(input())
if x < 0 and y > 0:
   print("Quadrant I")
elif x > 0 OR y > 0:
   print("Quadrant II")
else:
   print("Quadrant III")
```

Comment: Did you try to use `or` ?

Comment: your first `elif` should be AND, not OR.

Comment: `OR` should be lowercase `elif x > 0 or y > 0:`

Comment: Yes I've tried lowercase.... it did not work...

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what's an example of the input and failing output?

Comment: btw, Did you actually mean `elif x > 0 and y > 0:`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey but  AND I put it in `if x < 0 and y > 0:` , before `or`

Comment: Quadrant 1 is x < 0 *and* y > 0.  Quadrant 2 is x > 0 *and* y > 0.

Comment: Hi Andrea, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Python, 'OR' is to be 'or'

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x < 0 and y > 0:
   print("Quadrant I")
elif x > 0 or y > 0:
   print("Quadrant II")
else:
    print("Quadrant III")
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using `OR` you should use `or`.
Also you forgot to put indent in else statement.
I hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

I´ve tried like this and it worked for me.

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x < 0 and y > 0:
   print("Cuadrant I")
elif x or y > 0:
   print("Cuadrant II")
else:
   print("Quadrant III")
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything.